# Chrome/Brave do not launch after Ubuntu Server 22.04 installation

Tags: google-chrome, crash, brave

Neither Chrome nor Brave (nor the default browser) launch in my freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 server. I use Xfce and access via RDP.

I get the following errors for Chrome/Brave:

Brave browser:

```
[814:814:0213/104651.098757:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(158)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
[0213/104651.101555:ERROR:process_memory_range.cc(86)] read out of range
[0213/104651.101634:ERROR:elf_image_reader.cc(606)] missing nul-terminator
[0213/104651.107311:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)
[0213/104651.107361:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)
/usr/bin/brave-browser: line 48:   814 Trace/breakpoint trap   "$HERE/brave" "$@"
```

I'm new to Linux, so I'm very confused at this point.

Comment: Ubuntu Server is a text based system, where `brave` and `google-chrome` are both GUI web browsers.  Ubuntu Server (https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-server) doesn't come with a web browser so there is no default (it will use `lynx` or `w3m` which are text browsers).

Comment: ah sorry forgot to mention that I use xfce and access via RDP